# Can we always use the right hand side of Stokes's theorem?

Tags: stokes-theorem

Can we always use the right hand side of Stokes's theorem?
$$
\oint \vec{F} \cdot \vec{dl} = \int\int \nabla \times \vec{F}\cdot \vec{n}\ dS
$$

For example,

$$\vec{F} = z^2\hat{i} - 3xy \hat{j} + x^3y^3\hat{k}$$

$$z= 5-x^2 -y^2, z=1$$

Using the left hand side was easy, but I'm wondering if this is possible to compute this integral using the right hand side.
Or, maybe sometimes only the right hand side works?

Comment: The idea of the theorem is that, when the conditions for using Stokes' theorem are met, then instead of evalutaing the given RHS, only evaluate the LHS, because it is usually easier

Comment: All right, I wasn't sure. Thanks